# how to create row rapidly - Telerik Kendo UI MVC grid pop-up mode

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc, telerik-grid, telerik-mvc

I have a grid similiar [that](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/data-management/grid/how-to/Editing/cascading-dropdown-editors#popup-editing-mode). But I don't want to close pop-up window; after clicking update button, i want to save record and clear all (or some) fields and continue to create (other) new record. So user can re-insert new record rapidly (multiple insert in the same window).

Finally user click the "cancel" (or close) button and popup will be closed. How can I do that.

Answer (score 2):

Subscribe to Grid Edit/Save javascript events and follow the example below

```
var _PreventWindowClose = false;
var _IsNewMemberAlerted = false;

function onGridEdit(e) {
    var window = this.editable.element.data("kendoWindow");
window.bind("close", onWindowEditMemberClose);
}

function onGridSave(e) {
if (e.model.isNew() && !_IsNewMemberAlerted) {
    _IsNewMemberAlerted = true;
    _PreventWindowClose = true;
    }
}

var onWindowEditMemberClose = function (e) {
if (_PreventWindowClose) {
    e.preventDefault();
    _PreventWindowClose = false;
    doClearingFieldsIfNeed();        
}
else {
    _IsNewMemberAlerted = false;
    }
};
```

Comment: Rename function :) You can do your stuff here 'doClearingFieldsIfNeed' window now stay opened

Comment: ok @LayonezWronskey  now no error :).But  when I click update button second time It updates; but I want a new record.

Comment: This is just an example of how to prevent closing of window, for your case i think you need update datasource of that window directly in `doClearingFieldsIfNeed`