# Kendo UI MVC grid popup mode insert mode model.set not working for DropDownList

Tags: c#, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a sample like this [popup editing mode](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/data-management/grid/how-to/Editing/cascading-dropdown-editors#popup-editing-mode)

I want to store my model while first inserting, and set default values.

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<License>()
      .Name("popupGrid")
      .Columns(columns =>
      {
          columns.Bound(p => p.LicenseId).Width(20).Hidden().HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { @title = "License" });
          columns.ForeignKey(p => p.CustomerId, (System.Collections.IEnumerable)ViewData["customers"], "CustomerID", "CustomerName")
            .Title("Customer").Width(200);
          columns.Bound(p => p.VendorId).Width(20).HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { @title = "Vendor" });
          columns.Bound(p => p.ProductId).Width(20).HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { @title = "Product" });
          columns.Command(p => p.Edit().Text("Edit").HtmlAttributes(new { @title = "Edit" })).Width(80);
      })
          .ToolBar(toolbar => toolbar.Create().HtmlAttributes(new {@id ="MyAddButton" ,@title = "Add" }))
      .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.PopUp).TemplateName("PopupEditView"))
                  .Events(e => e.Edit("onGridEdit").Save("onGridSave"))
      .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
          .Ajax()
          .Model(model => model.Id(p => p.LicenseId))
              .Create(create => create.Action("Create", "Home").Type(HttpVerbs.Post))
              .Read(read => read.Action("Read", "Home").Type(HttpVerbs.Post))
              .Update(update => update.Action("Update", "Home").Type(HttpVerbs.Post))
          )
)

<script>   
        var myModel;
        function onGridSave(e) {
            if (e.model.isNew()) {
                myModel = e.model;
            }
        }   
        function onGridEdit(e) {
            if (e.model.isNew()&&myModel!=null) {
                e.model.set("CustomerId", myModel.CustomerId);
                e.model.set("VendorId", myModel.VendorId);
                e.model.set("ProductId", myModel.ProductId);
            }
        }
</script>
```

But it's not working. [image]

following code is not working too :

```
$(e.container).find('input[name="CustomerId"]').data("kendoDropDownList").value(myModel.CustomerId);//it's not giving error. but CustomerId is null in model of create method
```

Actually I want to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36333173/4458106). But I don't know how to update datasource while prevent closing window.

Answer (score 0):

You might try configuring your dropdownlist with `valuePrimitive: true`

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/dropdownlist#configuration-valuePrimitive

Comment: I have tried but unfortunately it did'nt work @Adam.